# Ajax call seems to be cached in IE11, how to force this call every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have an AJAX call this fires each time in Mozilla and Chrome, but not IE11. Thoughts appreciated.

```
function getOrders(customerId) {
  alert('Test1');
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/Orders/GetOrders',
    data: ({ customerId: customerId}),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: window.updateTable
  });

  alert('test 2');
}
```

Comment: Use the `cache: false` property of `$.ajax`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Or just add unused random data.

Comment: Just a couple of other suggestions, don't use `alert()` for debugging. `console.log()` is much better practice and accurate. Also you don't need the parentheses around the object you provide to `data`

Comment: Thanks to all. Like the cache: false idea.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful JS advice as well

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can provide the `cache: false` parameter to the `ajax` call.

A more generic method is to use a `cache-busting` technique. One common and easy way is to just append an extra bit of data to the URL. A timestamp works really well for this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '/Orders/GetOrders',
  data: ({ customerId: customerId, cacheBust: Date.now() }),
  dataType: 'html',
  success: window.updateTable
});
```

This would create a URL like this: `/Orders/GetOrders?customerId=123&cacheBust=123579285`. The nice thing is the timestamp will be different every call, so it'll essentially be a new resource and will not be cached.

This technique can be used to avoid browser caching in just about every case.